# Tool to batch convert DOI to citations?

Tags: citations, tools

I'm looking for an (online) tool to convert a long list of DOI's (1000+) into citation information. There are several tools that let you enter one DOI at a time, such as [doi2bib](http://www.doi2bib.org/#/doi) or [Crossref](http://www.crossref.org/guestquery/) but those would take too much time. I found one batch converting tool from the NCBI, but unfortunately it only works for medical publications (which these aren't). I would be fine with any type of citation style (I can process it to my needs).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia offers [citation tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Citation_tools) that generate citations from DOIs. You might see how those tools work, and whether you can use them outside Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this (which would require registering with them and obtaining an ID), but CrossRef provides a web service that appears to do what you need.  From the [documentation](http://help.crossref.org/using_the_open_url_resolver):

> Crossref query:
>
> https://doi.crossref.org/servlet/query?pid=username:password&id=10.1006/jmbi.2000.4282
>
> Like metadata queries, DOI query results are returned in XML format.

Once you have a username and password, you can construct a query URL for each DOI.  You'll then need to invoke that URL.  If I were doing this once I'd probably generate a shell script to call `curl` once per DOI and run it from the command line; if I expected to do this on a regular basis I might (coax somebody to) write a nicer client interface.

Note that that API is going to return XML; I presume it's the same XML that you get through the one-DOI-at-a-time web interface that you linked.